# Why does a value created inside a function borrow and how can I avoid this pattern?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm new to rust but an engineer of over 6 years in various other languages from Javascript to Go.

I'm wondering why here the value is borrowed when I convert the response body to an "object".

I understand that the function owns the value and then the value is destroyed when the function returns BUT functions exist to create and return values. So there's clearly something fairly big I'm missing here. Can someone set me straight?

```
let response = match self
    .client
    .index(IndexParts::IndexId(index, id))
    .body(json!({
        "index": index,
        "body": doc,
    }))
    .send()
    .await
{
    Ok(response) => response,
    Err(err) => {
        return Err(Box::new(err));
    }
};
let response_body = match response.json::<Value>().await {
    Ok(response_body) => response_body,
    Err(err) => {
        return Err(Box::new(err));
    }
};
let response_map = response_body.as_object();
Ok(response_map)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that the function owns the value and then the value is destroyed when the function returns BUT functions exist to create and return values. So there's clearly something fairly big I'm missing here.

You need to return an owned value, not a reference into a local. I assume what you're doing now boils down to:

```
fn foo() -> &Map<String, Value> {
    let x = serde_json::json!({}); // except you get it by http
    x.as_object().unwrap() // except you do proper error handling
}
```

This doesn't compile because you're returning the reference to a local value. Instead, you need to return the value itself:

```
fn foo() -> Map<String, Value> {
    let x = serde_json::json!({}); // except you get it by http
    match x {
        Value::Object(o) => o,
        _ => unreachable!(), // you'd return Err(...)
    }
}
```

But even this is more complicated than you need. Since you already deserialize the value yourself, and handle the errors, you can simply ask serde to deliver a `Map<String, Value>` to begin with:

```
let response_body = match response.json::<Map<String, Value>>().await {
    Ok(response_body) => response_body,
    Err(err) => ...
};
```

Of course, you'll also need to adjust the return type to return the actual value instead of a reference.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the effort you put into this

Comment: @Quesofat Thanks. And to address your question about creating values - the call to `response.json()` actually **did** create a value. It's just that `as_object()` is just a way to "peek" into that value, obtain a short-lived handle (reference) into it. Since Rust doesn't use a GC, returning such a handle is not allowed to compile, although such a thing would work in Go.

Comment: I wasn't looking closely enough to notice the ampersand. Passing a reference created in a function and that being destroyed after a function run make perfect sense to me vs the passing the actual value. Thanks again!